# Donut chart with single element data representation

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I have a donut chart with only one element data representation in that , i want to display the student marks progress of one subject in that .if the total marks are 40 fixed ,if student secured 20 marks then i have to show donut ring of 40 total and 20 secure in one color and remaining other color and exactly 20 is 50% of 40 , so the ring is 50 % filled .
sample image url:https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en-IN&q=circle&tbm=isch&imgil=-i9okmrsNWnMOM%253A%253B4SprfRuxEdGBNM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.jqueryscript.net%25252Floading%25252FSimple-Circle-Progress-Indicator-Plugin-with-jQuery-CSS3-Progress-Circle.html&source=iu&pf=m&tbs=simg:CAES1QEJmyL9JbxYb1cayQELEKjU2AQaAggKDAsQsIynCBpiCmAIAxIo8ga9ApUKoAmxFIUDmgr0BtAS8QazPcA9mCmhNJo9sj26KJY9_1zOjNBowkhxs4AjCwNn1av70aVKYZ8lLi4d1v8nTePPG-E8DP0ys8AhJfw1g-CDwjX177INFIAMMCxCOrv4IGgoKCAgBEgT3LCE-DAsQne3BCRo3CggKBmNpcmNsZQoHCgVzbWlsZQoGCgRzaWduCgoKCGdyYXBoaWNzCg4KDG9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbgw&fir=-i9okmrsNWnMOM%253A%252C4SprfRuxEdGBNM%252C_&usg=__miDKH8nE5s9Y45Nf-oFIrFA4CjQ%3D&biw=1303&bih=673&ved=0ahUKEwj28Za2s-PNAhWHQo8KHeljD3wQyjcISA&ei=6l1_V_bUB4eFvQTpx73gBw#imgrc=-i9okmrsNWnMOM%3A

[image: sample image]

Comment: What had you done so far? Put your code in jsFiddle so that I can further help you.

Comment: i am forgot to add plunker http://jsfiddle.net/s194pefo/2/

Comment: The best way to achieve such chart is using a gauge chart: https://jsfiddle.net/sxbrqyu4/3/ If you still want this to be a pie, you would need to wrap Highcharts code or add some dummy data to series to fill the rest of the pie.

Comment: thank you @morganfree , yes it is best suitable , but once logout of the application once again login it says error http://www.highcharts.com/errors/16 .If we load or refresh then we got the chart , do you have any idea to fix in angularjs application

Comment: @morganfree  do you know how to edit the chart title name

Comment: As error says it might occur if you load Highcharts twice or more on your webpage. To set title add title.text value in options https://jsfiddle.net/sxbrqyu4/5/